# Error handling and forwarding in Node.js for production

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

Please, I have setup up a domain to catch and handle exceptions in my application and avoid crashing of the application. It works but I want if I am doing the write thing since I also have this code

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
});
```

});

for error handling and usually, i get an error stating "can not set headers after the are set" which makes me believe the error handler middleware is already taking care of that. I need a little bit of guide to enhance the understanding of the efficient way error handling in node.js
code of domain

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
var reqDomain = domain.create();
reqDomain.add(req);
reqDomain.add(res);
reqDomain.on('error', function(err){
    console.log(err);
    res.statusCode = 500;
    res.render('errorpage');
});
reqDomain.run(next);
```

});

using this code snippet as an example, assuming there is an error how will the error be hangled.

```
router.get('/usermanage',checkloggedIn.isAdminOrProfessor,function(req,res){
    User.find({}, function(error,data){
       if(error){
           console.log(error)
            res.render('errorpage');
       } else{
           console.log(data)
           res.render('ManageUsers',{mydata:data,SuccessMessage: req.flash('SuccessMessage'), ErrorMessage: req.flash('ValidationError')});

       }
    });
```

});
and is it good idea to render errorpage if the callback return and error or it should rather be return err which will then forward,the error to the error handler?. I am a little confused with the ideal way of handling this. Any expect advise would be very much appreciated

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but *"headers already sent"* errors should generally be fixed, not handled, as it's a logical flaw you've made somewhere, trying to set headers after content is outputted.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution to my problem

```
router.get('/usermanage',checkloggedIn.isAdminOrProfessor,function(req,res,next){
    User.find({}, function(error,data){
       if(error){
           console.log(error)
            next(error)
       } else{
           console.log(data)
           res.render('ManageUsers',{mydata:data,SuccessMessage: req.flash('SuccessMessage'), ErrorMessage: req.flash('ValidationError')});

       }
    });
```

I forward the error to the errorhandler middleware and with that I defined two for each 404 and 500 error. which works well for me.